The way to narrow the spaces between icons on Dock
Is there any way to change the spacing between the icons in the Dock?
Example of icons:

These spaces between icons should be narrower.
I read these websites and could not get any benefit from them.

https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/844

https://old.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/bw2cbr/is_there_a_way_to_further_shrink_the_dock_from/epw6pu0/


